# XML Serialization when some node has no property

Tags: c#, xml

```
<TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
 <VOUCHER>
   <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
     <LEDGERNAME>Cellular Mobile Pte Ltd</LEDGERNAME>
     <AMOUNT>-2800000.00</AMOUNT>
   </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
   <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
     <LEDGERNAME>ABC Bank</LEDGERNAME>
   </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
 </VOUCHER>
</TALLYMESSAGE>
```

when I write this code

```
XmlNodeList dataNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("VOUCHER");
foreach (XmlNode voucharbrandnode in dataNodes)
   {                         {
     var amount=voucharbrandnode.SelectSingleNode("AMOUNT").InnerText
   }
```

this shows exception because there is no amount property in second node.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check node exist.

```
XmlNode xmlNode = voucharbrandnode.SelectSingleNode("AMOUNT");
var amount = "";
if (xmlNode != null)
amount = xmlNode.InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check node is exist or not :

```
if(voucharbrandnode.SelectSingleNode("//AMOUNT")!=null)
```